# Office 365 - Save Conflict error when upload Publishing page

Tags: sharepoint, cewp

I have some Publishing pages aspx.  When I tried to upload file to Site Contents -  Pages, I got error page popup like that:

"Sorry, something went wrong
Save Conflict
Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

In my aspx file have Content Editor Web Part.  If I delete all html in  in node  or If i don't delete html I have to set src="" and href="", I can upload aspx file successfully.

Then if my html with src="path" and href="path" I always got Save Conflict error.

What do I need to do ?

Comment: Instead of uploading full page why don't you update content editor web part only. You can use Powershell CSOM for SharePoint online.

Comment: I have more than 100 pages and each page have different contents in content editor web part so that i am trying to upload page.